# how to control the frame size in a Hub/Spoke topology

Tags: activemq-classic

I have errors on the Spoke when refusing to accept messages dispatched from the Hub:

> java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB

**Edit:** Full stack trace as requested by @JustinBertram

```
2019-03-22T13:15:11.821+01:00 | DEBUG | 0.33:59110@61616 | Transport                        | ivemq.broker.TransportConnection  231 | 167 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.11.0.redhat-630262 | Transport Connection to: tcp://1.2.3.4:56789 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.createFrameSizeException(IOExceptionSupport.java:52)[167:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.11.0.redhat-630262]
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:261)[167:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.11.0.redhat-630262]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:221)[167:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.11.0.redhat-630262]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:213)[167:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.11.0.redhat-630262]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)[167:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.11.0.redhat-630262]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_191]
```

Spoke network connector

```
<networkConnector name="SPOKE-TO-HUB" uri="static:(tcp://hub:61616)" duplex="true" networkTTL="5" decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" bridgeTempDestinations="false" userName="..." password="..."/>
```

Spoke and Hub transport connectors (port will be 61616)

```
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:0?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600" />
        <transportConnector uri="vm://local"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

The standard answer to fix this error is to increase the maxFrameSize.

If possible I would rather try to diminish the size of the dispatched frame to preserve the Spoke memory.

It is not clear what a frame is, hence I cannot make my decision on how to fix this issue.

Can someone clarify what I need to consider to make my  decision on the fix.

**Edit - extra thinking**
My understanding is that the Hub broker is trying to send messages to the Spoke broker and hits the 100 MB limit of the transport connector.

Lets says that I allow 1 GB to stream towards the Spoke, what will be the impact on the Spoke system?
I guess that the stream will be un-marshaled and the messages will be sent to the destinations.
Then the messages will be kept in memory if the destinations limit permits it (100Mb memory max in my case) or it will be persisted in the temporary storage and then it will be stored in the journal.

How much memory do I need to ensure that the Spoke will not crash?

Comment: Any chance you could provide the full stack-trace of that `IOException`?

Comment: @JustinBertram sure I'll post it tomorrow when I can access it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory is not not an issue for activemq, disks size is the limitation according to their documentation http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-activemq-to-hold-100s-of-millions-of-queue-messages.html

> ActiveMQ is not limited by memory availability, but by the size of the disk available to hold the persistent messages.

Upgrading the maxFrameSize is a solution